# Understanding subset notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So in this answer, user326210 used the notation, $f(W) \equiv \{ f(w) : w\in W\} \subseteq E$.
Maybe I am misunderstanding this but this part $\{ f(w) : w\in W\}$ is defined as the set of workers. How can the set of workers be a subset of E (which is itself the set of farms)..aren't they different?

Comment: $f: Farmers \to Farms$

Comment: $W$ is defined to be works but $f:W \to E$ and if $w$ is a farm**er**, then $f(w)$ is the **farm** that $w$ works on.  $\{f(w): w\in W\}\not \subset W$.  and $\{f(w): w\in W\}$ is defined to be the set if *farms* that all the farmers work on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$W$ is the set of workers.

$E$ is the set of farms.

And if $w \in W$ is a worker, $f(w)$ is the *farm* where $w$ works.

$f:W\to E$ and $\{f(w)| w \in W\}$ is *NOT* defined to be a set of workers.  $\{f(w)|w\in W\}$ is defined to be the set of farms where all the workers work.

The elements in $\{f(w)| w \in W\}$ are all the $f(w)$s; *not* the $w$s.  And every $f(w)$ is a farm; not a worker.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In the answer, $\left[\bigcup_{A\in f(W)} A \right] \subseteq F$, the left part means all the individual f(w) or all the farm are unioned.  The right side is just the set of farms ..so it means all the farms is a subset of the farm?

Comment: The LHS is all the farms that the workers work at.  The RHS is all the farms.  If every farm has workers the sets are equal.  Which is fine, every set is a subset of itself.  If there are farms that do not have workers then those farms are in the RHS but not the LHS and the LHS is a proper subset[*].  Either way, yes, all the farms the workers work at is a subset of all the farms.  ([*] Unless the $W$ is empty and there are no workers at all.  Then $\{f(w)|w\in \emptyset\}=\emptyset \subset F$ but it is not a proper subset. [the emptyset is a subset of every set.])